# Improving efficiency of row-split in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) which contains data as follows (just providing one row):

`df_raw_data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'checkin':datetime.date(2019, 01, 01), 
        'checkout':datetime.date(2019, 01, 05), 'booking_id':1234, 'tag':'A', 'rooms':2}, index = [0])`

I want to write a block of code that reads in every row of df_raw_data and creates a new df_split_data which turns every row of df_raw_data as follows:

```
df_split_data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date':[datetime.date(2019, 01, 01), datetime.date(2019, 01, 02), datetime.date(2019, 01, 03), datetime.date(2019, 01, 04)], 'checkin':[datetime.date(2019, 01, 01), datetime.date(2019, 01, 01), datetime.date(2019, 01, 01), datetime.date(2019, 01, 01)], 'checkout':[datetime.date(2019, 01, 05), datetime.date(2019, 01, 05), datetime.date(2019, 01, 05), datetime.date(2019, 01, 05)], 'booking_id':[1234, 1234, 1234, 1234], 'tag':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'rooms':[2, 2, 2, 2]})
```

Basically, every booking should be split into the number of days = (checkout-checkin) and get the date as a new column with the other columns remaining exactly the same.

I have tried doing this using a for loop as below

```
df_split_data = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df_raw_data)):
    df_1 = df_raw_data[i:i+1]
    df_1.reset_index(inplace = True)
    checkin_date = df_1['checkin'][0]
    checkout_date = df_1['checkout'][0]
    rooms = df_1['rooms'][0]
    booking_id = df_1['booking_id'][0]
    tag = df_1['tag'][0]
    los = df_1['los'][0]
    #los is a column which checkout - checkin in days
    datelist = pd.date_range(checkin_date, periods=los).tolist()
    datelist = [x.date() for x in datelist]
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'date':datelist})
    df_2['checkin'] = checkin_date
    df_2['checkout'] = checkout_date
    df_2['rooms'] = rooms
    df_2['booking_id'] = booking_id
    df_2['tag'] = tag
    df_split_data =  df_split_data.append(df_2)
```

Doing this gives the correct result, but takes a very long time to execute when there are 2 million+ entries.

Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to create your expanded DataFrame, then using [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to update the values in your `date` column:

```
df_split_data = df_raw_data.loc[
    df_raw_data.index.repeat(
        (df_raw_data['checkout'] - df_raw_data['checkin']).dt.days + 1)]

df_split_data['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_split_data['date']) + 
                         pd.to_timedelta(df_split_data.groupby(df_split_data.columns.tolist()).cumcount(), unit='d'))
```

[out]

```
      checkin    checkout  booking_id tag  rooms       date
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-05        1234   A      2 2019-01-01
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-05        1234   A      2 2019-01-02
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-05        1234   A      2 2019-01-03
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-05        1234   A      2 2019-01-04
0  2019-01-01  2019-01-05        1234   A      2 2019-01-05
```